# c# chart excel style

Tags: c#, charts, excel-interop

I can't manage to change the style of my excel chart in C#.

I have this: 
[default design](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RiCt9.png)

and i would like to get this:
[design I try to have](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cuQko.png)

I read a lot of topics on this subject, tried a lot of them and nothing seems to work...
I managed to get what I wanted for my pie chart but it's not working for my "Column" Chart:

I tried this:

```
object paramChartFormat = 1; //tried to change it to 201, 209, ... not working :(
```

then this (found the name with a macro in excel as I seen it was the way to get the name of the design we wanted on another question here on stackoverflow) but the design is still the "standard" with blue columns:

```
Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.XlChartType.xlColumnStacked;
```

Here's my code:

```
        object paramChartFormat = 1;
        object paramCategoryLabels = 1;
        object paramSeriesLabels = 1;
        //bool paramHasLegend = true;
        object paramTitle = "Collection";
        object paramCategoryTitle = "";
        object paramValueTitle = "";
        Range dataRange = null;
        ChartObjects chartObjects = null;
        //ChartObject newChartObject = null;
        object paramMissing = Type.Missing;
        string tuple = "C" + Row.ToString();
        dataRange = sheet.get_Range("A1", tuple);
        chartObjects = (ChartObjects)(sheet.ChartObjects(paramMissing));
        /*newChartObject = chartObjects.Add(0, 100, 300, 300);
        newChartObject.Chart.ChartWizard(dataRange, XlChartType.xl3DColumn, paramChartFormat, XlRowCol.xlRows, paramCategoryLabels, paramSeriesLabels, paramHasLegend, paramTitle, paramCategoryTitle, paramValueTitle, paramMissing);
        */
        //Number of copies
        Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.ChartObject chartObjectnbex = sheet.ChartObjects().Add((float)sheet.get_Range("B1").Left, (float)sheet.get_Range("B"+(Row+2).ToString()).Top, 300, 300);
        chartObjectnbex.Chart.ChartType = Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.XlChartType.xlColumnStacked;
        Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Series seriesnbex = chartObjectnbex.Chart.SeriesCollection().Add(sheet.Range["B2:B" + Row.ToString()]);
        seriesnbex.XValues = sheet.Range["A2:A" + Row.ToString()];
        seriesnbex.Name = "Nombre d'Exemplaires";
        //Nbre documents différents
```

//this code (pie chart is working):

```
 Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.ChartObject myChart = (Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.ChartObject)chartObjects.Add((float)sheet.get_Range("B1").Left, (float)sheet.get_Range("B" + (Row + 77).ToString()).Top, 300, 300);
            Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Chart chartPage = myChart.Chart;

            Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.SeriesCollection seriesCollection = chartPage.SeriesCollection();
            Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Series series1 = seriesCollection.NewSeries();
            series1.XValues = sheet.Range["A2", "A"+Row.ToString()];
            series1.Values = sheet.Range["B2", "B" + Row.ToString()];
            chartPage.ChartType = Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.XlChartType.xlDoughnut;
            chartPage.HasTitle = true;
            chartPage.ChartTitle.Text = "Nombre d'exemplaires";
            Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Axis axis = chartPage.Axes(Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.XlAxisType.xlValue, Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.XlAxisGroup.xlPrimary) as Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Axis;

            series1.ApplyDataLabels(Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.XlDataLabelsType.xlDataLabelsShowPercent, true, true, false, false, false, false, true);
```

Have you an idea of what i'm doing wrong to change the design?

Thanks a lot,

R.

Answer (score 0):

I found what I was doing wrong. I had only one serie and so it was considering all my numbers as a group. I wrote this code and voilà, it's working:

```
             //Nbre documents différents
            Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.ChartObject chartObjectnbdd = sheet.ChartObjects().Add((float)sheet.get_Range("E1").Left, (float)sheet.get_Range("B" + (Row + 2).ToString()).Top, 300, 300);
            chartObjectnbex.Chart.ChartType = Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.XlChartType.xlBarClustered;
            chartObjectnbdd.Chart.HasTitle = true;
            chartObjectnbdd.Chart.ChartTitle.Text = "Nombre de documents différents";
            Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.SeriesCollection seriescollnbdd = chartObjectnbdd.Chart.SeriesCollection();
            Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Series seriesnbdd = null;
            i = 2;
            while (i <= Row)
            {
                seriesnbdd = seriescollnbdd.NewSeries();
                seriesnbdd.Name = excel.Cells[i, 1].Value.ToString();
                seriesnbdd.Values = sheet.Range["C" + i.ToString() + ":C" + i.ToString()];
                i++;
            }
```

The output (The only thing now is the "1" I can't figure how to erase but it's ok):

[Chart with colors](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SKcRy.png)

Thanks everyone!